# Changing a div with a remote javascript file

Tags: javascript, remote-server

There is page X on server x with a html file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pageYserverY.com/remote.php?hat=strong"></script>
<div name="lev">Hallo world</div>
```

Consider the JS file is included from a remote server Y.

The file on page Y (remote.php) looks like this:

```
<?php
    Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
    $hat = $_GET["hat"];
    echo "document.write(\"$hat\");"; // write it once
?>
document.getElementsByName("lev").innerHTML="Hello World AGAIN";
```

Why is it not changing the div. Is my whole approach and my understanding of cross-browser JS wrong?

btw: the calling a php generated js is a approach google itself uses on recaptcha and google ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find it is simply an ordering problem. The JavaScript is executing before the div is ready.

Move the script beneath the div, like so:

```
<div name="lev">Hallo world</div>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://pageYserverY.com/remote.php?hat=strong"></script>
```

Comment: thx bruder. using jquery and doc.ready made me blind to see the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Is better that you use `getElementById` that `getElementsByName`.

The `GetElementsByName` method returns an array, and when you tried to call `element.focus()` you got an error because there is no `focus` method on an array. When you get an error in the event handler it won't prevent the form from posting.

If you use `GetElementById` you should use `element` to access the element, and if you use `GetElementsByName` you should use `element[0]`.

Repeat

```
getElementById gets an element via an id. getElementsByName returns an Array of elements by their name.
```

Then this is work:

```
<div id="lev">Hallo world</div>

<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$hat = $_GET["hat"];
echo "document.write(\"$hat\");"; // write it once
?>
document.getElementById("lev").innerHTML="Hello World AGAIN";
```

Comment: was part of the problem. +1 . have a nice day